# undefined method `picture' for nil:NilClass using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, carrierwave, image-uploading

I am making a form in my rails application where people have the option of adding images and I am using 'carrierwave' but I am getting an undefined method error on the edit page. Here is the code for the form:

```
<%= title "Add Item to #{@todo_list.title}" %>

<%= form_for [@todo_list, @todo_item], builder: FoundationFormBuilder do |form| %>
  <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { form: form } %>

  <%= form.file_field :picture %>

<% end %>
```

Here I can see the upload button and it is working fine but on the edit page I get the above stated error. Code for my edit page:

```
<%= title "Editing Todo Item" %>

<%= form_for [@todo_list, @todo_item], builder: FoundationFormBuilder do |form| %>
   <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { form: form } %>
<% end %>

<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    <%= link_to "Delete", todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, @todo_item), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "button radius expand alert" %>
  </div>

  <%= @todo_item.picture %>

</div>
```

Why is this showing an undefined method error. I tried creating a method in my todo_item model but its still showing the above error.

Controller for todo_item:

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_user
  before_action :find_todo_list
  before_action :set_back_link, except: [:index]

  def index
    go_back_link_to todo_lists_path
  end

  def new
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new
  end

  def create
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new(todo_item_params)
    if @todo_item.save
      flash[:success] = "Added todo list item."
      redirect_to todo_list_todo_items_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was a problem adding that todo list item."
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
    if @todo_item.update_attributes(todo_item_params)
      flash[:success] = "Saved todo list item."
      redirect_to todo_list_todo_items_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "That todo item could not be saved."
      render action: :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
    if @todo_item.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Todo list item was deleted."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Todo list item could not be deleted."
    end
    redirect_to todo_list_todo_items_path
  end

  def complete
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
    @todo_item.toggle_completion!
    redirect_to todo_list_todo_items_path, notice: "Todo item updated."
  end

  def url_options
    { todo_list_id: params[:todo_list_id] }.merge(super)
  end

  private

  def set_back_link
    go_back_link_to todo_list_todo_items_path(@todo_list)
  end

  def find_todo_list
    @todo_list = current_user.todo_lists.find(params[:todo_list_id])
  end

  def todo_item_params
    params[:todo_item].permit(:content)
  end

end
```

Comment: @todo_items is nil  You sure it shouldn't be @todo_item?

Comment: Already tried, no change

Comment: Then you should show where @todo_items exists in the code above

Comment: You are right it should be @todo_item and I have changed that but its still not working

Comment: Let me edit my question

Comment: @Rohit can you post your controller

Comment: @Mandeep I have added my controller but I don't understand that how is it relevant to the error

Comment: What you meant by **still not working**? Did you got same `error` again?

Comment: Yes I am getting the same error again

Comment: which browser are you using? Are you sure it's not cached because `<%= @todo_item.picture %>` should work

Comment: Google Chrome. How can I check if its getting cached?

Comment: @Rohit check in firefox or close that tab and open another one i have also encountered this problem in chrome. Don't know why but sometimes chrome doesn't reflect changes in html or css

Comment: Suddenly I am not getting the error anymore but thing is that nothing is happening now. I can't see the image that I uploaded. Tried both firefox and chrome

Comment: Let me explain the working,the button to add image is on the new.html.erb while the code for image display is on edit page

Comment: I checked the source of the page and saw this `<img src="" />`, is this right? Shouldn't there be a visible link in img src=""

Answer (score 0):

To display your image you should change

```
<%= @todo_item.picture %>
```

to

```
<%= image_tag(@todo_item.picture_url) %>
```

Comment: Still no image is being displayed. I don't understand what's happening :/

Comment: @Rohit Are you getting any errors and are you sure that you have picture for that todo_item?

Comment: I am not getting any error and how can I be sure? I mean how can I check? But the source of the page shows `<img src="" />` Does this mean something?

Comment: @Rohit yeah your to_do doesn't have image. Check in your db by some GUI tool or in rails console query your database. How else will you check it :)